# Flask, cambiar input según información de otro input

Tags: javascript, python, flask

He estado haciendo una WEBAPP, e ido poco a poco investigando y aprendiendo, estoy trabajando con python y flask, poco a poco he metido javascritp, css, para sortear algunas cosas, pero me he topado con algo que no he podido superar que es lo siguiente:

Tengo una linea de inputs para un articulo "X".

Cod barras, descripción, precio, cantidad, total.

Lo que deseo es que al indicar el código de barras, automáticamente se llenen los inputs de descripción y precio.

Agradecido de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

luego de investigar un poco mas, di con la siguiente solución (quizá no lo mas correcto, pero me funciona):

se creo una clase diccionario y luego la use para crear un json de mi consulta en la BD. (no coloque todo el código)

```
@app.route("/ventas", methods=["POST", "GET"]) 
def ventas():
    if request.method == "GET":
        mydict1 = create_dict()
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM clientes")
        data2 = cur.fetchall()
        for row in data2:
            mydict.add(row[1],({"descripcion":row[2],"precio":row[3]}))
            stud_json = json.dumps(mydict, indent=2, sort_keys=False, cls=DecimalEncoder)
       cur.close()
        
        return render_template("ventas.html", prod = stud_json)
```

Recibí el json en la pagina de la siguiente forma:

```
<script>
  function cargar_objetos() {
  object1 = {{ prod | safe }};
  var array_obj = Object.keys(object1);
}

window.onload=cargar_objetos;
</script>
```

Luego, así maneje el código de barras para que me dejara la descripción y los demás datos de forma automática:

```
function buscar1(){
  m1 = document.getElementById("codbarras1").value;
  m2 = document.getElementById("multiplicador").value;
  d = object1[m1];
  descri = d.descripcion;
  preci = d.precio;
  t = m2 * preci
  document.getElementById("des1").value = descri;
  document.getElementById("pre1").value = preci;
  document.getElementById("resultado").value = t;
}
```

Y en el HTML tengo varios div con sus respectivos ID que reciben los resultados de mi función buscar1.

A quien pueda funcionar.
Y si alguien puede mejorarlo (estoy seguro que si) es bienvenido.

Ahorita estoy tratando con jquery a ver como me va en la creación de los div de forma mas optimizada y se calcule los totales de mejor forma.